# Is there a difference between OP_PUSHBYTES and OP_PUSHDATA

Tags: script, development, opcodes

In some documentation about Script we sometimes have to use `OP_PUSHBYTESx` or `OP_PUSHDATAx` to indicate that some number of bytes will be an element to read.
They seem to do the same thing so is there a reason they have different names ?

Comment: In what documentation ? I believe you are talking about how `rust-bitcoin` refers to the OPs `> OP_FALSE` and `< OP_PUSHDATA1`

Comment: When you click on "Display Script" on this page https://tbtc.bitaps.com/3dd3d1ec850769aac2359efd642ebe292e60502fc17dc33d7be1bc3cc6678621/mvEg6eZ3sUApodedYQrkpEPMMALsr1K1k1 and https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script

Comment: Ok; it's what rust-bitcoin does too. Writing an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In what documentation? I believe you are talking about how `rust-bitcoin` refers to the OPs `> OP_FALSE` and `< OP_PUSHDATA1` and will answer as such.

There are multiple OP codes pushing bytes to the stack, defined as integers.

#### Special case: pushing small integers

There are dedicating OP codes for pushing integers from `-1` to `16` (named [`OP_1NEGATE`, `OP_0` and `OP_1` to `OP_16` and valued `0x4f`, `Ox00` and `0x51` to `0x60`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/e31af1065e8a4a9dbb294e980047a135d4233962/src/script/script.h#L68-L91)).

They are used for instance for (smallish) multisigs as it saves you 1 byte per number pushed compared to using a "real" push opcode.

#### "`PUSHBYTES`": pushing small byte arrays

The (not named in the reference implementation) [OP codes valued from `0x01` to `0x4b`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/script.h#L68-L70) allow to [push from 1 (`0x01`) to 75 (`0x4b`) bytes to the stack](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/e31af1065e8a4a9dbb294e980047a135d4233962/src/script/script.cpp#L296-L303).

They are commonly used to push pubkeys and signatures.

#### `PUSHDATA`: pushing byte arrays

The [`PUSHDATA1`, `PUSHDATA2` and `PUSHDATA4` (`0x4c`, `0x4d` and `0x4e`)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/e31af1065e8a4a9dbb294e980047a135d4233962/src/script/script.h#L70-L72) operands are used to push a byte array to the stack which size is defined as a [variable-length integer](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Variable_length_integer) .

#### Further: too many encodings!

This flexibility of encoding introduced malleability in the `scriptSig`, which was not protected by the signature (which it carries).
[BIP62](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0062.mediawiki#Push_operators) proposed to restrict this encoding to avoid possible malleation.